# Combine array index values in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to merge arrays into one and output in json_decode to use foreach.

Request Output

```
$option = [
  0 => '"["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]"',
  1 => '"["Option 1.1", "Option 1.2"]"'
];
```

Desired Output

```
array:2 [
  0 => "["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 1.1", "Option 1.2"]"
]
```

I've tried

```
$option = $request->option_c;
$arrMerge = array_merge($option);
dd($arrMerge);
```

But I'm getting undesired results.

Hope someone can help me on this.

Comment: Maybe you just need `["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 1.1", "Option 1.2"]`?

Comment: So the Request output shows the contents of $option?

Comment: Yes but that's not what I'm getting. the $request->option_c is both have own index and I want to combine them and convert to json and use in foreach

Comment: Your expected output is a string, should it be string or array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `...` to merge a multidimensional array.
The problem is that you have strings that is array looking. These can be json_decoded I we trim off the leading and trailing `"`.

```
$arr = [
  0 => '"["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]"',
  1 => '"["Option 1.1", "Option 1.2"]"'
];
foreach($arr as &$a) $a = json_decode(trim($a, '"'), true);
var_dump($arr);
var_dump([0=>array_merge(... $arr)]);
```

https://3v4l.org/VrfIY

To avoid confusion in the future, always var_export your arrays when you copy paste them here, that way we can use with exactly what you have.

Comment: I've already tried this example but this is the message i'm getting. "message": "array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, string given",

Comment: Then $option is not what you say it is

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your array elements are JSON encoded arrays? Then decode them first:

```
$arr = [
    '["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]',
    '["Option 1.1", "Option 1.2"]'
];
$arr = array_map('json_decode', $arr);
```

Then use the spread operator(`...`). It spreads out the contents of the array($option) so that array_merge() receives each post of it as a separate argument, i.e `array_merge(...$option);` "becomes"/"should be read as" `array_merge($option[0], $option[1]);` (in this particular case).

```
$arr = [
    ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"], 
    ["Option 1.1", "Option 1.2"]
];
$result = array_merge(...$arr);
```

Note: Spread for arrays works for PHP7.4+

Answer (score 0):

You may need the [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections).

```
$datas = collect([['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3'], ['option 1.1', 'option 1.2']]);
$datas->flatten()->toArray();
```

Output:

```
[
    "option 1",
    "option 2",
    "option 3",
    "option 1.1",
    "option 1.2",
]
```

---

Edit : using your variables :

```
$datas = collect($request->option_c)->flatten()->toArray();
```

Comment: The output I'm getting on your example is

0 => array:2 [
      0 => "["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]"
      1 => "["Option 3", "Option 4"]"
    ]

am I doing this correctly? $datas = collect([$request->option_c]);